Hot to handle Checksum Mismatch in Messages Sent from Indiko Analyzer Machine
Body:
I am currently working with an Indiko analyzer machine and encountering a consistent issue with checksum mismatches in the ASTM messages sent from the machine. I've noticed that the checksums calculated by our system do not match the expected checksums, typically off by a consistent margin. Below are the details of the checksum calculation and examples of the mismatches:
Checksum Calculation Process:
The checksum is supposed to be calculated by summing the ASCII values of each character in the message, taking the result modulo 256, and converting that result into a two-digit hexadecimal representation. This calculation excludes any STX (0x02) and ETX (0x03) control characters. Here's how we implement it in Java:
private static String calculateChecksum(String data) {
    int checksum = 0;
    for (char c : data.toCharArray()) {
        checksum += (int) c;
    }
    checksum %= 256; // Modulo 256 to fit within one byte
    return String.format("%02X", checksum); // Return as two-digit hexadecimal
}

Examples of Messages and Checksums:

Message: 1H|\^&|||1^Analyzer 1^7.0|||||||P||20240806002716

Expected Checksum: E4
Calculated Checksum: D4


Message: 2Q|1|^2240801398^^||^^^ALL^||||||||O

Expected Checksum: 53
Calculated Checksum: 43


Message: 3L|1|N

Expected Checksum: 06
Calculated Checksum: F6



Interestingly, for some messages, the checksum calculation matches exactly as expected. For example:

Message: 1O|1|20240804231803|^^^GLU||R|||||||^20240804231803

Expected Checksum: BD
Calculated Checksum: BD



Question:
What could be causing this consistent offset in the calculated checksums? Are there common pitfalls or specific considerations in ASTM protocol implementations that might lead to such discrepancies? Any suggestions on how to adjust the checksum calculation or message preprocessing to resolve these mismatches would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you so much for any one in advance for any insights or advice on how to troubleshoot and resolve this checksum issue!

Everything I'm seeing about the ASTM checksum indicates that the checksum should include the trailing carriage return (that I don't see in your data) and the ending ETX.

But the carriage return comes after the checksum.
MessageCheckSum
